# How can i decouple this project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, decoupling

I have a scenario where my business layer has a direct reference in the form of a dll to my database layer which is acting as the repository in this project, now this means there is a direct dependancy on the database layer which would need decoupling, please see structure below:

[image: Project Structure between Business layer and Database Layer]
   [image: Business layer directly referring to database]

I know how to use DI and containers for this, but i would like some tips and how to decouple this in some form without having to add a IRepository interface in the business layer and the database layer having concrete repositories calling the irepository in the business layer. Does this make sense at all.

I have a repository interface which sits in the Database_Layer dll :

```
 public interface IRepository
 {
    Task Add(Object item);

    Task Remove(int id);

    Task<Object> Find(int id);

    Task UpdateAsync(Object item);

    Task<IEnumerable<Object>> GetAllAsync();

    Task<IEnumerable<Object>> GetAllAsync(Object id);
}
```

Then i have a class in the Business tier called ContentPanel :

```
using Database_Layer.Interfaces;
namespace Business_Tier.Concrete
{
public class ContentPanel : IPanel
{
    IRepository _repository;
    public ContentPanel(IRepository repo)
    { 
        this._repository = repo;
    }

    public IResolver _Resolver { get; set; } = null;
    public IResolver Resolver { get => _Resolver; set => _Resolver.Resolve<IRepository>("ContentRepository",_repository); }

    public void Delete_Content_Panel(int id)
    {

    }
```

}

I want to eliminate the using reference the database_layer.interfaces and just resolve the repository dependancy, would i have to define the repository interface in the Business layer, in order to do this?

Comment: You don't have clear understanding about how DI works and why interfaces are important here. If you have any approach thought of doing DI with concrete class please try implementing it and tell us what issue you face in that.

Comment: Decoupling things doesn't necessarily mean removing entire references - at that point you're looking at plugins etc, which is another topic entirely.

Comment: but there is a direct dependancy on the database layer in the Business layer would you not agree with that.

Comment: See [Ioc/DI - Why do I have to reference all layers/assemblies in entry application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9501604/181087)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You business layer(dll) have a dependency on your data access layer(dll)

You need to use an interface to abstract the business layer contract from the data access implementation

Using DI in the Startup project will allow you to inject the desired implementation to that interface

You business layer will have always a physical dependency in the data access layer but will not have a dependency in the data access implementation.

Comment: i get the startup resolving of the dependancy, but how can i get rid of the dll dependancy,  data access implementation would be the concrete repositories

Comment: so essentially it doesnt really eliminate the physical dependancy though does it?

Comment: No it does not, think about it, you need to pull data right? so you need a bridge to  that data pulling.

Comment: The point of using interfaces is to hide implementation so your business layer does not know about how things are done.

Comment: hidden implementations got it, ok, so here is my two cents then from this learning exercise, essentially i register and resolve all my dependants in the startup right, and then in this scenario i can use the DataBase.Interfaces namespace which is calling the iRepositry and resolve it in the contentPanel class in the Business layer using the registered service in the startup right?

Comment: Yeah thats right, you use your interface in the business layer, injecting the concrete from the startup proejct

Comment: I know where do you come from and where do you want to go, so to save to you some pain, if you want to get better at this, read, practice and repeat

Comment: SOLID (object-oriented design) and Test-driven development (TDD) should be a good point to start

Comment: so essentially, what i have currently is correct and in line with seperation of concerns as well, only thing is resolving the dependancies

Comment: yes i have a scenario where my entire business tier is unit testable and i can pass mocked objects as domain objects

Comment: Yeah yo do, but sometimes is difficult to identify theory from the practical example, good luck mate, this is way to long :)